# How can I export bookmarks in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Some months ago I could export bookmarks in Google Chrome. Only in HTML format but that was much better than nothing. Now with the latest update I can't save them. I went to bookmark manager (chrome://bookmarks/) and I can't find any export option.

Later edit: when I go to Bookmarks manager I can't find any "Organize" and export option. The Bookmarks manager looks very different than before. My computer has Chrome 43.0

I checked on another computer where the Chrome version is 35.0 and I could find those options and I could save the bookmarks.

I just can't save them from this version of Chrome.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu.
2. Select Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager.
3. Click the "Organize" menu in the manager.
   Select Export bookmarks.

[Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en)

[image: exporting bookmarks in chrome]

Comment: Organize menu is located on the top. These steps worked perfect.

Comment: The Organize menu is the **title** of the right hand column that shows the contents of the folder selected in the left hand column. Hands down, that is the most non-intuitive place for it.

Comment: This is really a hidden place. I didn't spot that "Organize" text even after reading in the help file that such a menu should be there.

Comment: This let me falsely think what it exports are limited to items currently shown in the right pane instead of all, because is above the right pane.

Answer (score 3):

Export bookmarks from Chrome

1.In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu.

2.Select Bookmarks > Bookmark Manager.

3.Click the "Organize" menu in the manager.
 Don't see the "Organize" menu? Try using the alternate directions below.

4.Select Export bookmarks.

Chrome will export your bookmarks as an HTML file, which you can then import into another browser.

Chrome Help [Link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en)

Comment: Another way copy the xml file in your chrome settings folder

Comment: Thanks, I've found it in "C:\Users\<My User>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Bookmarks"

Answer (score 2):

### **Export Bookmarks from Chrome**

Open **Chrome** and press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**Shift**</kbd>+<kbd>**O**</kbd> to open the **Bookmark Manager**. Now click the dropdown arrow beside **Organize**, select **Export bookmarks to HTML file...**, and now save the file somewhere you can find and access later to import, etc..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export only a group of bookmarks rather than all your bookmarks, you can select the ones you want to export in the Bookmark Manager and either copy or drag them into a text or Word file. I don't know if you can import this type of file as is, but this method will allow you to save a list of the bookmarks as hyperlinks. If you want just the raw links without the page titles you can copy & then "Paste And Match Style" from the Edit menus on Mac and you'll have a list of the URLs.

Comment: That *is* what I want to do. Dragging isn't working on mac. Copy and paste does work, but just for the URLs as you say. Shame that the bookmarks manager doesn't offer this when we select a folder

Comment: Hmm, ok - I'm on Mountain Lion and dragging is working for me (selecting the bookmark(s) should highlight them and then allow you to drag into a text file). If you do a regular paste (command+v) it should give you the bookmark titles as hyperlinks. If you select "Paste And Match Style" (shift+command+v) then it should give you just the URLs.

The Bookmarks Manager should actually allow you to do this as well though. Select the folder in the left column, select Copy from the drop-down menu, and then paste into text file to get all the bookmarks as hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I've found the following:

On my Windows 10 x64, in **Chrome** there is a file named "Bookmarks" (also a backup - "Bookmarks.bak") inside this folder:

C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

(replace "MyUser" with your own user name)

I am also using **Chromium** (various versions), and I'm installing them into "C:\Programs", and there the location of the Bookmarks file is the following:

C:\Programs\Chromium-55\Data\Profiles\Default\Bookmarks

This "Bookmarks" file contains all the bookmarks, so keeping a copy of this is a good way to backup the bookmarks. To restore an old bookmarks backup, just copy the old version you want to restore over this file, while Chrome (or Chromium) is closed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install this bookmark manager from Google.
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-manager/gmlllbghnfkpflemihljekbapjopfjik
2. You can find the export menu in there