# Combine shared and local bookmarks in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I use more computers on different locations and I use shared bookmarks in Chrome to have the same bookmarks everywhere. (I mainly use bookmarks on the toolbar, but that is probably not important. By "shared" I mean that I login to Chrome to see the same bookmarks for my user everywhere.)

Due to different internet connectivity, I need to have one particular bookmark customized on each computer. Because the address I need to use in the bookmark is different for each ISP. How can I achieve this? Is there some simple way, or can it be achieved by pointing the bookmark to some redirection file on local drive or something?

Comment: Try this https://superuser.com/a/919961/726810

Comment: @Biswapriyo that doesn't help. I do not need to export anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody provided a solution, so I tried to figure it myself. I put a link to a local file to Chrome's favorites bar. It is as simple as `file:///C:/users/username/something.html`

The something.html file looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0; URL=https://realserver.com/">
</head>
</html>
```

Then I just copy this html file to all my computers and edit the "realserver" address on particular ones.